# angular test service

Tags: angular, test, karma-jasmine, jasmine

Soy nuevo en las pruebas con angular y tengo un problema al intentar hacer una en angular, sucede lo siguiente que tengo un servicio que hace uso de un ENUM, el cual no logro hacer que lo tome el servicio al momento de realizar la prueba.

Tengo este servicio:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import {
  FLOW_URLS_DEFINITION,
  SacMicroservices,
  SacURLsDefinition,
} from '../models/back-config.model';
import { PostalCodeInterface } from '../../tasks/address/pages/address-form/models/address-form.model';
import { Cacheable } from 'ts-cacheable';

@Injectable()
    export class PostalCodesService {
      constructor(
        @Inject(FLOW_URLS_DEFINITION) private sacURLsDefinition: SacURLsDefinition,
        private httpClient: HttpClient
      ) {}
    
      public getPostalCodes(id: number): Observable<PostalCodeInterface> {
        return this.httpClient.get<PostalCodeInterface>(
          this.sacURLsDefinition.base +
            this.sacURLsDefinition.microservices[SacMicroservices.MASTER_DATA]
              .path +
            this.sacURLsDefinition.microservices[
              SacMicroservices.MASTER_DATA
            ].operations.getPostalCodes(id)
        );
      }
    }
```

y este es el test relacionado:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        HttpClientTestingModule,
      ],
      providers: [
        PostalCodesService,
        { provide: FLOW_URLS_DEFINITION, useValue: sacURLsDefinition },
      ],
    });
    // Inject the http service and test controller for each test
    httpClient = TestBed.inject(HttpClient);
    httpTestingController = TestBed.inject(HttpTestingController);
    service = TestBed.inject(PostalCodesService);
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should return file', () => {
    // Arrange
    const expectedData: PostalCodeInterface = {
      addressColony: [
        ...
      ],
    };
    let dataError, dataResponse;
    // Act
    service.getPostalCodes(1)
      .subscribe(response => {
        dataResponse = response;
      }, error => {
        dataError = error;
      });
    const req = httpTestingController.expectOne(`${environment.baseURL}/file`);
    req.flush(expectedData);
    // Assert
    expect(dataResponse).toEqual(expectedData);
  });

});
```

SacMicroservices archivo - back-config.model:

```
import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';

export const FLOW_URLS_DEFINITION = new InjectionToken<SacURLsDefinition>(
  'EP_BACK'
);
export const FLOW_EXIT_URL = new InjectionToken<string>('FLOW_EXIT_URL');
export const ENROLLMENT_URL = new InjectionToken<string>('ENROLLMENT_URL');
export const INACTIVITY = new InjectionToken<string>('INACTIVITY');
export const APPLICATION = new InjectionToken<string>('APPLICATION');

export enum SacMicroservices {
  COP = 'COP',
  MASTER_DATA = 'MASTER_DATA',
  PERMISSION = 'PERMISSION',
}
export interface SacURLsDefinition {
  base: string;
...
}
```

Cuando ejecuto los test me genera el siguiente error:
[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fiL4O.png)

```
Error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'MASTER_DATA')
            at PostalCodesService.getPostalCodes (projects/ui-banba-lib/src/lib/shared/services/postal-codes.service.ts:25:5)
            at PostalCodesService.propertyDescriptor.value (node_modules/ts-cacheable/dist/esm2015/cacheable.decorator.js:70:1)
            at UserContext.<anonymous> (projects/ui-banba-lib/src/lib/shared/services/postal-codes.service.spec.ts:61:13)
            at ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-evergreen.js:372:1)
            at ProxyZoneSpec.push.QpwO.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:301:1)
            at ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-evergreen.js:371:1)
            at Zone.run (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-evergreen.js:134:1)
            at runInTestZone (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:581:1)
            at UserContext.<anonymous> (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:596:1)
            at <Jasmine>
```

He probado a ponerlo como providers pero no lo toma, alguien sabe como podría  solucionarlo? tambien trate de generarlo como propiedad dentro del test pero tampoco.

Comment: ¿Puedes incluir los imports? Parece ser que este problema surge cuando tienes dependencias circulares

Comment: Estos son los imports: `import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import {
  FLOW_URLS_DEFINITION,
  SacMicroservices,
  SacURLsDefinition,
} from '../models/back-config.model';
import { PostalCodeInterface } from '../../tasks/address/pages/address-form/models/address-form.model';`

Comment: puedes [edit] la pregunta y añadir el código ahí, será mucho más legible que en un comentario. ¿Tienes también `import` en `back-config.model.ts`?

Comment: @PabloLozano Si, también tengo import en el back-config.model.ts, lo incluí en la pregunta también aunque es solo el InjectionToken.